# bitcoind rpc interface, generate method deprecated in version 0.19.0 (latest)

Tags: bitcoind

How to generate a block in the new version of bitcoind.

> bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 1

The above command no longer works with the latest bitcoind package

I want to confirm a transaction I have executed under the regtest mode for bitcoind, hence generating a block to confirm the tx.

Answer (score 4):

`generate` was deprecated and removed in favor of `generatetoaddress`.